# Wordpress post settings not available

Tags: wordpress

When editing a wordpress page, the advanced sections (custom fields, discussions, etc) are not just there. Sections created by plugins and themes **are** available.
It's a new WP installation and the problem appeared instantly. I can't recall a setting for that anywhete...

Comment: Maybe a good idea to post on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the posts page (where you would edit the post and expect to find the custom fields box).

Up in the upper left side there are screen options that allow you to select what you would boxes you would like to see under the edit post field.

These options are different for each page withing the dashboard.